# How to check if Array contains ClosedRange?

Tags: arrays, swift, range

In my application written in Swift 4.2 I have the following code:

```
let arrayOfIntegers = [2, 1, 9, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7]
let unknownLowerBound = 4
let unknownUpperBound = 20
let closedRange = ClosedRange<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: unknownLowerBound,
                                                     upper: unknownUpperBound))
let subRange = arrayOfIntegers[closedRange]
subRange.forEach { print($0) }
```

As you can guess when I am running this code I receive the following error: `Fatal error: Array index is out of range`. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted and contiguous? Do you want to know if all elements of the range are included in the array? Do you simply want to check if the array contains that range of elements or do you also want to retrieve them from the array?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Array may not be sorted. No, it is enough if Array contains at least 1 item of ClosedRange. And I want to print the items that I retrieved from ClosedRange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the range of valid array indices “clamped” to
the given closed range is equal to that range:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let closedRange = 4...20
if array.indices.clamped(to: Range(closedRange)) == Range(closedRange) {
    let subArray = array[closedRange]
    print(subArray)
} else {
    print("closedRange contains invalid indices")
}
```

Or, equivalently:

```
if array.indices.contains(closedRange.lowerBound)
    && array.indices.contains(closedRange.upperBound) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Here is a cute one: `if Set(array.indices).isSuperset(of: closedRange)`

Comment: @Carpsen90: Yes, but `Set(array.indices)` creates a (potentially large) set of all indices. The above methods operate only on the lower and upper bound of ranges.

Comment: If we're talking efficiency, would this be slightly better: `if (array.indices.lowerBound <= closedRange.lowerBound)
        && (array.indices.upperBound >= closedRange.upperBound)`? Looking at the bounds, I suspect, is faster than `contains`. *(The first solution does create two ranges)*

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just prints out contains Invalid Indices

Comment: @Junaid: It is *expected* that the above example prints “closedRange contains invalid indices” because not all numbers in the given range are valid indices for the array.

Answer (score 1):

To check for `ClosedRange<Int>` and `Range<Int>`

Remember that `Range` does not include the `upperBound`

```swift
private extension Array {
    func contains(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Bool {
        indices.contains(range.lowerBound) && indices.contains(range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

```swift
private extension Array {
    func contains(range: Range<Int>) -> Bool {
        range.lowerBound >= 0 && range.upperBound <= count
    }
}
```